# When is memory of temporary objects released

Tags: c#, .net

If I have the following code

```
Public int SomeFunct()
{
    int temp;
    Int32.Parse(txtbox.Text, out temp);
    return temp;
}
```

I am using a temporary int. So after the function execution is over, when is the memory of the int (or any temporary object used) released?
Or, is there any code to be called explicitly?

Comment: As James said, the garbage collection will free the memory at an unknown future time. You can force the garbace collection to run with `GC.Collect()` though, but that should happen outside your function, because inside, the temp variable is still in scope.

Comment: The GarbageCollector will take care of this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Usually you should not call `GC.Collect` except for some really weird and rare causes. So simply don´t care for it and let garbage-collector do its. work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case most likely the `temp` variable is either allocated on the stack, or in a register.

I say "most likely" because the exact workings of this level of code is implementation specific as far as I know.

On the stack it will be deallocated when the method returns. If it is placed in a register then the register will be reused at some point and will cease any specific meaning when the method returns.

In this case I think that to summarize, it will be "deallocated" when the method returns.

Also note that while all types in .NET inherits from `System.Object`, the phrase "object" is usually used by reference types. `int` is a value type, which is not allocated on the heap.

If you also mean "what happens to temporary *objects*" then the garbage collector will collect those at some later indeterminate point in time.

For instance this piece of code:

```
public void Log(int value)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Here we are using [this overload of Debug.WriteLine that takes an `object` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7821bed5(v=vs.110).aspx). In this case the `int` value will be [boxed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) which means an object will be allocated on the heap to hold our `int`.

This temporary object will be used by `Debug.WriteLine` and then no longer be considered "in use". At some future indeterminate point in time, the garbage collector will collect it.